# Getting values from one table to insert into other table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This code is not getting value of radio button which are used in switch cases. I have to get values from one table to save into another table.
Please tell me where I am making mistake, and how to solve this issue.

```
$qry="select * from quiz";
        $result=mysql_query($qry);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<br>". $row['QuestionNo']." ". $row['Question']. " " . $row['NoOfOptions'];
            ?>  

            <form method="post" action="quiz.php" >        
            <?php 
            $noofoptions = $row['NoOfOptions'];
            switch ($noofoptions)
            {   
                Case 0:
                        echo "<textarea col='50' row='4' name='subjectiveanswer'></textarea>";
                break;      
                Case 1:
                ?>  A: <?php echo $row['OptionA'];?><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['OptionA'];?>"> <?php
                break;
                case 2:
                ?>  A: <?php echo $row['OptionA'];?><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['OptionA'];?>"> <?php
                ?>  B:<?php echo $row['OptionB'];?><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['OptionB'];?>">  <?php
                break;
                case 3:
                ?>  A: <?php echo $row['OptionA'];?><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['OptionA'];?>"> <?php
                ?>  B:<?php echo $row['OptionB'];?><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['OptionB'];?>">  <?php
                ?>  C:<?php echo $row['OptionC'];?><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['OptionC'];?>">  <?php
                break;
                Case 4:
                ?>  A: <?php echo $row['OptionA'];?><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['OptionA'];?>"> <?php
                ?>  B:<?php echo $row['OptionB'];?><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['OptionB'];?>">  <?php
                ?>  C:<?php echo $row['OptionC'];?><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['OptionC'];?>">  <?php
                ?>  D:<?php echo $row['OptionD'];?><input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['OptionD'];?>">  <?php
                break;          
            }

            ?>
            <div class="button"><a href ="quiz.php?Save=<?php echo $row['QuestionNo'] ; ?>"> Save   </a></div>                      

                <?php echo "<hr />";  ?>
            </form>

            <?php   

        }                    
                if(isset($_GET['Save']))
                {   
                    if(isset($_POST['option']))
                    {
                        $a = $_POST['option'];
                    } else 
                    {
                            echo " answer is not set "; exit;
                    }

                    $q= $_GET['Save'];

                    SaveAnswer($q,$a);


                }
```

Comment: I dont see you send a radio? I mean you dont send a form... ?

Comment: it is mentioned in while loop.<form method="post" action="quiz.php" >

Comment: your form is in a while loop?  are you trying to generate a form with PHP?If so, you can go the oop route instead.

Comment: No I don't want to generate form with PHP. I just want to get Question No and answer from quiz table and pass these variable to saving function for inserting another table. Those I have saved question no in variable using $_GET variable but answer is not being assigned to $a using $_POST.

Comment: ok, Ill try to ask diferently: Where do you submit form?

Comment: I am trying to submit form on every record level. Because I have to save every question separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather using get method you can pass `questionNo` value in hidden and retrieve it from php side. also you will need to change Save button with type submit as :

```
<input type="hidden" name="QuestionNo" value="<?php echo $row['QuestionNo']?>" >
<input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable **Save** in

```
<div class="button">
<a href ="quiz.php?Save=<?php echo $row['QuestionNo'] ; ?>">Save</a>
</div>
```

never gets submitted for two reasons: the url the form would be sent to is **quiz.php** (in `<form method="post" action="quiz.php" >`), not **quiz.php?Save=xy**, the second being the form is never submitted (no submit button).

Turn the link into a submit button, e.g. `<button>Save</button>`, otherwise the form will never be submitted. Append `?Save=<?php echo $row['QuestionNo'] ; ?>` to the form's url and it should work as expected.